# Find all docs where field doesn't exists, plus if field exists apply condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to make a query that:

- if certain field exists, it will apply condition on the field and if it pass, it will add return document and add it to the results.
- **and** if such field doesn't exist, it will also add document to the results?

In the end we will receive all documents where certain field have matched condition **AND** all document where such field doesn't exist at all.

Comment: what is the problem with $exists http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: It will return only documents that have that specific field.

Comment: You may be able to use `$or`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
db.stackoverflow.find({
  $or: [
    { howmuch: { $exists:false } },
    { howmuch:5 }
  ]})
```

In the stackoverflow collection, this will find all documents that do not have the `howmuch` field plus all documents that do have `howmuch` set to 5.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I went in totally different direction. Thanks!

Comment: since the OP tagged his question with the `mongoose` tag, I think this is the best place to post this comment: 
for anyone using Mongoose 6.x, You can't perform a search query for a field that does not exist in your schema, if you want to do so, you must specify the `strictQuery` options to false in your schema, but read the documentation first because you shouldn't be doing that unless you know what you're exactly doing.