# Mongodb query - apply condition to subfield only when field exists

Tags: mongodb

I need to find a document either when a field doesn't exist or when a subfield of this field meets some condition.

A similar question was asked here: [Mongodb query - apply condition only if field exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030328/mongodb-query-apply-condition-only-if-field-exists). I'll use the code from this answer to illustrate:

```
db.stackoverflow.find({
  $or: [
    { howmuch: { $exists:false } },
    { 'howmuch.chocolate':5 }
  ]})
```

Of course when I do that I get an error when `howmuch` is undefined. I know I could test if `'howmuch.chocolate'` exists but that wouldn't change anything. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.stackoverflow.find({
  $or: [
    { howmuch: { $exists:false } },
    { $and: [{ 'howmuch.chocolate': { $exists: true } } ,{ 'howmuch.chocolate':5 }]}
  ]})
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/), if the first expression in the `$and` array evaluates to false, the remaining expressions are not evaluated.

Comment: Why this should work if OP's query failed? Perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: @user3100115 Using the `$and` operator, the error will be prevented as the check for the field will be performed first, and if that fails, the second part (which was causing the error) is not evaluated.

Comment: I thought of that but missed the part that said that if the first expression evaluates to false, the remaining expressions are not evaluated. Thanks a lot! I'll read the docs more carefully next time :)