# MongoDB find all docs where field doesn't exists, plus if exists apply field operator ($max) condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am looking for a query for a `$match` stage in my aggregation which do *almost* the same, as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030328), but..

- if field (named rank in my case) doesn't exists in document, add document to results
- but if field, exists, apply [`$operator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) condition (in my case it's [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/)) to this field, and add all documents that suits this condition to the results.

[MongoPlayground with example collection](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G0WYWm7kkdn).

Result should be like this:

```
[
  {
    "method": 3,
    "item": 1,
    "rank": 3 //because it has field named rank, and suits condition {rank: $max}
  },
  {
    "method": 4,
    "item": 1 //we need this, because document doesn't have rank field at all
  },
  {
    "method": 5,
    "item": 1 //we need this, because document doesn't have rank field at all
  }
]
```

Things, that I have tried already:

```
            {
                $match: {
                    $or: [
                        {item: id, rank: {$exists: true, $max: "$rank"}}, //id === 1
                        {item: id, rank: {$exists: false}} //id === 1
                    ]
                }
            }
```

> UPD: As for now, probably I don't limit with `$match` stage only, `$project` is also relevant after default match, so I could request every document during `$match` stage by `id` no matter, have the doc `rank` field or not, and then, during `$project` stage do a "separation" by rank `$exists`

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do... In your sample + expected result, you skip first 2 documents... Please provide valid sample / expected result...

Comment: @Valijon Is it? I want to find every doc from the collection that doesn't have a certain field, but if it has it, the apply condition to this field. And this condition should have a field operator. Guess, it couldn't be more simple than that.

Comment: Now it's more clear, thanks. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      item: id
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",   //<- Change here your searching field
      max: {
        $max: "$rank" //<- Change here your field to apply $max
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $type: "$data.rank"
              },
              "missing"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              "$data.rank",
              "$max"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data"
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wuMT1aKRV_E)

Comment: Y, thank you for that, you was faster/better then me, so I accept it, as an answer. Also I'm currently working on variant, based on `$project` stage with `$ifNull`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer, separated from @Valijon's method, but it's also based on the logic above. My query is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      item: id
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      method: 1,
      item: 1,
      rank: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$rank",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$item",
      data: {
        $addToSet: "$$ROOT"
      },
      min_value: {
        $min: "$rank"
      },
      max_value: {
        $max: "$rank"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              "$data.rank",
              "$max_value"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              "$data.rank",
              "$min_value"
            ]
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

My query is based on `$project` stage which gives the empty field value 0. It also could be -1, or any value that isn't used in collection. And then I separate results.

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XTFN7xFPp6W)